# How can I print a text field's database value with devel so that it displays on all nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, debugging

I want just the text field's data without an of the "field-" divs wrapped around it. It's a link so I want to do something like `<a href="foo.com"><?php print render($content['field_download_link']); ?></a>`.

`$...['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7533]['field_download_link']['#field_nam‌​e']` is the path of the field I want to display, but I want it on every node of the content type feed_item, not just 7533.

I tried placing `<?php dpm($node); ?>` at the top of node--feed-item.tpl and `<?php print dpm($node['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7533]['field_download_link']['#field_nam‌​e']); ?>` where I want the field, but it just causes the page to load without any css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check the full structure of $node try this:

**var_dump($node)**

In this case looks like you need something like this:

**echo $node->FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value'];**

If you want to get an image field.. you can use this:

**echo render(file_create_url($node->IMAGE_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['uri']))**

Comment: @user4343348 Cool, remember to put this into a loop if you have more than one value for each field

Comment: How do I do that? I'm bad with php. Also do you think using this for every field would be a better alternative to a module like Fences?

Comment: The [0] part means that you are working with the first child of your field... if you have a field with more than one values you need to put it into a loop, like this:
<?php 
foreach($node->FIELD_NAME['und'] as $myField){
 print $myField['value'];
}?>

So it will print ['value'] for each item of your field. And yes, i think this is better than using a module, it's pretty much flexible

Answer (score 0):

Based on [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7), it says

> $node: Full node object. Contains data that may not be safe.

### Things I noticed that's not quite right:

1. `dpm()` doesnt need to be used with `print`
2. `dpm($node['content']['system_main']['nodes'][7533]['field_download_link']['#field_nam‌​e']);` wouldn't work since $node is an object.

### Things to try:

1. Use only `dpm($node);` and see what's the output. If the field you're looking for exists then you can continue with manipulating its data
2. you could place the structuring of your link in `hook_preproess_node()` and just render it into your template file.